# Matrices that satisfy $x*y+y=z$

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I need to solve this problem. Find, if they exist, all the matrices $4\times4$ with coefficients in $\Bbb Z_7$ such that $x*y+y=z$ where y and z are the following matrices.

$y=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\
2 & 4 & 1 & 3
\end{matrix}\right)$ and $z=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 2 & 4 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
1 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{matrix}\right)$

I have no idea how to solve this problem but a half approach I tried is the following. I assume it's equivalent to reasoning with the corresponding reduced matrices. So I reduced the two matrices to try to do some calculation and I obtained:

$y=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$ and $z=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$

So basically the only way to obtain the equivalence is when $x$ is the null matrix. I don't know if it is the correct way to reasoning but that's the only thing I've been thinking about at the moment. Any idea?

Comment: Is the $*$ matrix multiplication?

Comment: @Tyler6 Yes, it is

Comment: But *why* do you need to solve that problem?

Comment: usually, $x*y+y=(x+I)y.$ So you only need so solve $uy=z$, if possible, and then set $x=u-I.$

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'm practicing some linear algebra exercises...

Comment: I think you should try "reduce" the whole equation more appropriately, keeping track of the elementary operations or inverse matrices introduced

Comment: Since the determinant of $y$ (as computed by Wolfram Alpha) is $2$ modulo $7$, $y$ is invertible.

Comment: What do you mean you "reduced the matrices?" Why can you do that? How does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{aligned}
XY+Y&=Z\\
XY&=Z-Y\\
X&=Y^{-1}\cdot(Z-Y)
\end{aligned}

so you only need to find inverse matrix of $Y.$

Comment: ... which you can easily find by inverting over $\mathbb{Q}$ and then reducing modulo $7$, taking modular inverses of denominators.